# How to get customer registration form into CMS page

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, cms-pages

Is possible to create a CMS page with some content and Magento registration form .The registration form will function same as the default register form,when submitting the registration form the data will be passed to database.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your Magento CMS page.

```
{{block type="Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register" template="customer/form/register.phtml"}}
```